# temporarily_unavailable on linkedin servers

Tags: c#, json, oauth, linkedin-api

I am new to work with linkedin programming and try to get some user data, however I can't get further than https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken where I get this response the whole time:

> {"error":"temporarily_unavailable","error_description":"the authorization server is currently unable to handle the request : RestException{_response=RestResponse[headers={X-LinkedIn-Error-Response=true, Content-Length=6936, X-Restli-Protocol-Version=1.0.0, Server=Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)},status=404,entityLength=6936]} "}

I am using the following url with parameters:

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQR4LKsR8tswI4o-Ej0bE6vg1fhAZntPuT26CFMFEhZZh7zFkLM7PyxRRp5XEzZ-Y45vIBwZam8zDncMECldDrCSJI8WKNlxrR5gsAcxmkga0ZzIM38&redirect_uri=http://localhost:30731/redirect.aspx&client_id=OAuth User Token&client_secret=OAuth User Secret

The error I get within C# is that the server is unavailble which corresponds with the JSON message.

Anybody does know the solution or has the same error or a solution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temporarily_unavailable` is an error code defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0). For this error code, all you can do is just wait for the authorization server to come back to its normal state.

If the authorization server always returns `temporarily_unavailable`, there must be a bug in the implementation of the authorization server.

Comment: Not answering my question but already what I thought. It's very strange as this is the core server from linkedin to connect to this content, very weird.....