# Retrieving access token for LinkedIn Login

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to provide linkedin login to my website users, for which I'm using the instruction from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 link. At this point I'm able get the authorization code, however when I use the same for requesting access token it gives me the following error:

```
Description: {"error_description":"the authorization server is currently 
unable to handle the request : RestException{_response=RestResponse[headers=
{Content-Length=7907, Server=Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106), X-LinkedIn-Error-Response=true, 
X-RestLi-Protocol-Version=1.0.0}cookies=[],status=404,entityLength=7907]} ",
"error":"temporarily_unavailable"}
```

Now I know, a similar question was asked and marked and complete on stackoverflow [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343070/temporarily-unavailable-on-linkedin-servers), the answer to it isn't solving the issue. The server seems to always be unavailable. Please anyone kindly help me to understand as to why this is happening.

I using php curls to post data in order to retrieve access token.

Comment: Would you be able to post the link of the question you had found and the results of when you tried to use that solution?

Comment: FWIW status=404 stands out as the Not Found HTTP error

Comment: @Newd Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343070/temporarily-unavailable-on-linkedin-servers